# Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running './gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.12.10'

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

I am trying to download Apache Kafka and I see comments on StackOverflow to download the binary files to remove this issue.I downloaded the binary downloads.

[image]

I found the solution in `windows` to do the following changes:

```
  To over come this add below given lines in your kafka-run-class.bat present inside C:\confluent-community-6.0.1\confluent-6.0.1\bin\windows folder
```

to add this code above the line:

```
rem classpath addition for LSB style path by siddhu
if exist %BASE_DIR%\share\java\kafka\* (
call:concat %BASE_DIR%\share\java\kafka\*
)
```

I am using `linux` and I downloaded the .tar file and extracted it in `New Volume` Drive.

```
/media/ashwin/New Volume/sparkcourse/workspace/sparkwithjava/kafka_2.11-2.4.1/bin/windows
```

I see the kafka-run-class.bat file and i added the same code but it's not working for me.

I see output as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Linux, you need to completely ignore the bin/windows folder.

Also, if you're downloading Kafka from the Apache site, there is no Confluent folder, so I'm not sure what you're referencing about changing files around since Linux cannot run bat files anyway.

Regarding the title of your post, that's typically a sign you've downloaded the source code for Kafka, and not the already built binaries, which should work without editing any files.

You need to run `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh` and `bin/kafka-server-start.sh`, which are mentioned in the quickstart section of the docs

Comment: I see USAGE: bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh [-daemon] zookeeper.properties
and USAGE: bin/kafka-server-start.sh [-daemon] server.properties [--override property=value]* when i entered your script. I have pasted the new screenshot please see that

Comment: Yes, you need to provide a config file. Please read the documentation https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart